# What are the difference between the prefixes in a terraform execution plan?

Tags: terraform, hcl

This is [the explanation the docs](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/aws-change) give:

> The prefix -/+ means that Terraform will destroy and recreate the resource, rather than updating it in-place. While some attributes can be updated in-place (which are shown with the ~ prefix), changing the AMI for an EC2 instance requires recreating it. Terraform handles these details for you, and the execution plan makes it clear what Terraform will do.

> Additionally, the execution plan shows that the AMI change is what required your resource to be replaced. Using this information, you can adjust your changes to possibly avoid destroy/create updates if they are not acceptable in some situations.

And this is the sample CLI output:

```
$ terraform apply
aws_instance.example: Refreshing state... [id=i-08e568120498007f8]

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_instance.example must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_instance" "example" {
      ~ ami                          = "ami-830c94e3" -> "ami-08d70e59c07c61a3a" # forces replacement
      ~ arn                          = "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:561656980159:instance/i-08e568120498007f8" -> (known after apply)
      ~ associate_public_ip_address  = true -> (known after apply)
      ~ availability_zone            = "us-west-2c" -> (known after apply)
      ~ cpu_core_count               = 1 -> (known after apply)
      ~ cpu_threads_per_core         = 1 -> (known after apply)
      - disable_api_termination      = false -> null
      - ebs_optimized                = false -> null
        get_password_data            = false
      - hibernation                  = false -> null
      + host_id                      = (known after apply)
      ~ id                           = "i-08e568120498007f8" -> (known after apply)
      ~ instance_state               = "running" -> (known after apply)
        instance_type                = "t2.micro"
      ~ ipv6_address_count           = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ ipv6_addresses               = [] -> (known after apply)
      + key_name                     = (known after apply)
      - monitoring                   = false -> null
      + outpost_arn                  = (known after apply)
      + password_data                = (known after apply)
      + placement_group              = (known after apply)
      ~ primary_network_interface_id = "eni-055ef36f8a8672b0e" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_dns                  = "ip-172-31-6-208.us-west-2.compute.internal" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_ip                   = "172.31.6.208" -> (known after apply)
      ~ public_dns                   = "ec2-34-211-82-197.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
      ~ public_ip                    = "34.211.82.197" -> (known after apply)
      ~ secondary_private_ips        = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ security_groups              = [
          - "default",
        ] -> (known after apply)
        source_dest_check            = true
      ~ subnet_id                    = "subnet-31855d6c" -> (known after apply)
      - tags                         = {} -> null
      ~ tenancy                      = "default" -> (known after apply)
      ~ volume_tags                  = {} -> (known after apply)
      ~ vpc_security_group_ids       = [
          - "sg-0edc8a5a",
        ] -> (known after apply)

      - credit_specification {
          - cpu_credits = "standard" -> null
        }

      + ebs_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_name           = (known after apply)
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = (known after apply)
          + volume_type           = (known after apply)
        }

      + ephemeral_block_device {
          + device_name  = (known after apply)
          + no_device    = (known after apply)
          + virtual_name = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ metadata_options {
          ~ http_endpoint               = "enabled" -> (known after apply)
          ~ http_put_response_hop_limit = 1 -> (known after apply)
          ~ http_tokens                 = "optional" -> (known after apply)
        }

      + network_interface {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_index          = (known after apply)
          + network_interface_id  = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ root_block_device {
          ~ delete_on_termination = true -> (known after apply)
          ~ device_name           = "/dev/sda1" -> (known after apply)
          ~ encrypted             = false -> (known after apply)
          ~ iops                  = 0 -> (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          ~ volume_id             = "vol-0e8a0961912e2ab59" -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_size           = 8 -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_type           = "standard" -> (known after apply)
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

I understand the `-/+` prefix before `resource "aws_instance"` -- it means the instance will be terminated and recreated with the the AMI.

What I don't understand are the differences between `~`, `-`, and `+` in the itemized list below it. For example, in the code snippet above, it seems arbitrary that security groups gets a `~` in front of it while the specific security group name `default` gets a `-` before it.

This is not preventing me from accomplishing something, I'm just curious about those syntax decisions, so that I can maybe get a deeper understanding of Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

TerraForm Symbols

```
    + create
    - destroy
    -/+ replace (destroy and then create, or vice-versa if create-before-destroy is used)
    ~ update in-place
    <= read
```

The last one applies only to data resources. You won't see this one often.

Check out This Discussion : https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14379

Note: TerraForm always tells you the symbols meaning that are presented in terraform plan like this:

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement
```

Comment: This answer would be improved if you could link to an official source at all?

Comment: Could you please expand on the example of how those symbols make sense in the case of `~ security_groups` and `- "default"` in the given CLI output? At face value, this means the security groups get updated in place, and the default security group gets destroyed. This, of course, is not what actually happens though, since the `.tf` template only included an EC2 instance and this update only changed the AMI ID. Also, why not put `-/+` in front of most items on the list? The previous instance had an EBS volume too, but the list only has a `+` next to `ebs_block_device`.